# Present Text file on webpage

Tags: php, text-files

I have a text file `"applications.txt"` I want to show on the web using PHP, I have this line of code:

```
<?php
    $myfilename = "applications.txt";
    if(file_exists($myfilename)){
        echo file_get_contents($myfilename);
    }
?>
```

The contents of the text file looks like this:

> Line one
>
> Line two
>
> Line three

However, on the webpage, it looks like this:

> Line one Line two Line three

How do I make it display the new lines properly?

Comment: replace the new line with a <br /> try using `nl2br();`

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns the contents verbatim, if the file is not HTML don't expect it to render correctly as HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because HTML ignores more than two concurrent whitespaces and treats them as a single one.  You can wrap the output in `<pre>` tags

```
echo "<pre>" . file_get_contents($myfilename) . "</pre>";
```

that will preserve the file as it appears but can lead to problems for files with long lines.  You can also replace newlines with `<br/>` tags using `nl2br()`

```
echo nl2br(file_get_contents($myfilename));
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML uses `<br/>` markup to make a line return, you should either do a foreach line and display a 
 markup, or use a `pre` markup to disregard formatting.